# Is log-likelihood bounded for continuous variables?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, maximum-likelihood

Let $(x_i,y_i)$, $i=1,...,N$, be an i.i.d. dataset. Suppose we have a  parametric distribution $f(y|x,\omega)$, parameterized by $\omega$, and we want to find the value $\omega^*$ such that $f(y|x,\omega^*)$ is the *best* approximation of the true distribution $p(y|x)$.

A usual criterion is the maximization of the *likelihood* of the $y_i$'s conditioned on the $x_i$'s, i.e.:

$\newcommand{\argmax}{\mathop{\mathrm{arg\,max}}}$
$\omega^* = \argmax_{\omega} f(y_1,...,y_N|x_1,...,x_N,\omega) =\argmax_{\omega} \prod_{i=1}^{N} f(y_i|x_i,\omega)$.

(the equality above holds due to the assumption that the examples in the dataset are independent)

For practical reasons, it is usual to work instead with the following (equivalent) formulation:

$\newcommand{\argmin}{\mathop{\mathrm{arg\,min}}}$
$\omega^* = \argmin_{\omega} \sum_{i=1}^{N} -\log(f(y_i|x_i,\omega))$

(these formulations are equivalent because the $\log(\cdot)$ function is monotonic)

For convenience, let me define $L(\omega)=\sum_{i=1}^{N} -\log(f(y_i|x_i,\omega))$ and call it a *loss* function.

If the $y_i$'s are discrete random variables, then $f(y|x,\omega) \leq 1$ and, therefore, $L(\omega) \geq 0$ for all $\omega$, so our loss function is always non-negative and so it is lower bounded.

If, instead, the $y_i$'s are continuous random variables, then $f(y|x,\omega)$ is a pdf and so it is not necessarily less than $1$ (although it integrates to $1$ w.r.t. $y$). Under these circumstances, is it possible to ensure that $L(\omega)$ is lower bounded (i.e. that the optimization problem actually has a solution regardless of the model family)? Is there any obvious lower bound for it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What if its a location family $f(y-\theta)$ where $f(y)\sim 1/\sqrt(|y|)$ for $y$ near $0$?

Comment: Didn't understand what you mean, sorry

Comment: Sorry: I was hasty and didn't pay close attention to your notation.  I mean, what if $f(y|x,\omega) = 1/\sqrt{|y-\omega|}\times g(y|x,\omega)$ where $g$ depends on its arguments smoothly.  Then your likelihood function will have an infinitely high spike in $\omega$  at each $y_i$ value.

Comment: I suppose in that case $f(y|x,\omega)$ would not be a proper pdf, in the sense that it doesn't integrate to 1.

Comment: But $\int_{-1}^1 1/\sqrt{|y|} \,dy < \infty$, so I don't understand your "I suppose..."  There are unbounded density functions.

Comment: Yes, you are right, my mistake. I was seeing that integral as unbounded, but it is bounded in fact.

Answer (score 0):

There is no lower bound in general. Here is a counter-example !

Consider a single point $x_0$ and choose to model it using a Gaussian distribution with mean $x_0$ and an unknown variance $\sigma^2$.

The negative log-likelihood writes
\begin{equation}
\ell(\sigma,x_0) = \log\left(\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma\right)
\end{equation}
and has no lower bound.

This is the reason why it is important to choose appropriate models and to regularize your model using priors. For example, using a [Frechet prior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_distribution) with $m=0$, $s=1$ and $\alpha=2$ for the standard deviation then the negative log-posterior writes
\begin{equation}
\ell_p(\sigma,x_0) = \log\left(\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma\right) + \log\left(\frac{\sigma^3}{2}\right) + \frac{1}{\sigma^2}.
\end{equation}
One can show that $\ell_p$ has a lower bound ($\sigma > 0$).

Comment: Can you clarify a bit what you mean when you say that $x_0$ has expectation $x_0$? This does not seem to be a valid probability distribution to me, but maybe I'm wrong and you can write down a pdf that integrates to 1 that represents what you mean.

Comment: Waw, it's a long time ago. I think my counter-example is quite degenerate case in which the modeler is trying to model a single possible observation with a Gaussian distribution (a very bad choice ^^). Retrospectively I would say it's a bad counter-example because it's not very appropriate to use a distribution with support on the real line to model a singleton.